# How to manage div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have three div with `col-md-2, col-md-8 and col-md-2`.

what i want is that on clicking a button in `col-md-8` div both the remaining div should hide and the `col-md-8` div occupy the full `col-md-12` space.

Again on clicking the button in the `col-md-8` div both the `col-md-2` div appear again and the centeral `col-md-8` div occupy the space of `col-md-8.`

Is this achievable  by jquery if yes then how and in case no then what should i do?
Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Spartan i got my answer, hope now it will help you to clarify my specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Here is a snippet which show you a way to achieve it.
Hope it helps!

```js
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
  if ($( "#two" ).hasClass( "col-xs-8" )) {
    $( "#one" ).hide();
    $( "#three" ).hide();
    $( "#two" ).removeClass( "col-xs-8" );
    $( "#two" ).addClass( "col-xs-12" )
  }
  else {
    $( "#one" ).show();
    $( "#three" ).show();
    $( "#two" ).removeClass( "col-xs-12" );
    $( "#two" ).addClass( "col-xs-8" )
  }
});
```

```css
#one {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

#two {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

#three {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2" id="one"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8" id="two">
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Hide</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what i was looking for.